# Request.Querystring(variablevalue) possible?

Tags: asp-classic, request.querystring

I'm creating an application which uses request.querystring to transfer variables between pages. However at the moment I am setting variable names in the URL dynamically in accordance with an array and I want to retrieve these values on another page using (essentially) the same array. So I came up with what I thought would be the simple solution:

```
For Each x In AnswerIDs
    response.write(x)
    ctest = Request.Querystring(x)
    response.write(ctest)
Next
```

However this doesn't seem to work as it looks like you can't use `Request.Querystring()` with a variable as it's parameter. Has anyone got any idea how I could do this?

This is the query string:

> QuizMark.asp?11=1&12=1

In this case AnswerIDs consists of "11" & "12" so in my loop I want it to write "1" & "1".

Comment: Can you add the querystring you're using? That might give some more insight in your problem.

Comment: What you are trying to do should work but if it isn't, just a guess, but as Request.QueryString is expecting a string for the key try: ctest = Request.Querystring(CStr(x))

Comment: @John no I just tested, and numbers can be keys. The problem is probably in the confusing display that using the given example will be plain "111121".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can loop through the querystring like this:

```
For Each Item in Request.QueryString
    Response.Write Item & ": " & Request.QueryString(Item) & "<br/>"
Next
```

Item contains the name of the querystring parameter, with Request.Querystring(Item) you retrieve the value of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your method will work with a simple modification:

```
For Each x In AnswerIDs
    response.write(x)
    ctest = Request.Querystring(CStr(x))
    response.write(ctest)
Next
```

If your array might have Null elements, then replace the `Cstr(x)` with `x & ""`.

If, on the other hand, you can make sure that every element of AnswerIDs has a value (i.e. is neither Empty nor Null), then you can omit the string conversion. In other words, the problem isn't with calling Request.Querystring with a variable, but with calling Request.Querystring with an Empty or a Null.